# Replace a nested object with another object

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I want to replace a nested object with another object.

Is this the simplest way to express that?

```
r.expr({ foo: {bar: 1}, eck: true })
 .merge({ foo: null }, { foo: {zim: 1} })

// Expected output: { foo: {zim: 1}, eck: true }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `r.literal` for this: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/literal

```
r.expr({ foo: {bar: 1}, eck: true })
 .merge({ foo: r.literal({zim: 1}) })
```